# SQL Server calculate average score per user per day but where some users have no recorded score for some days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my first post, so take it easy with me :-).  I'm trying to get a SQL query that will give me average score per day per user.  The data is being used to plot a chart, so I need a consistent timeline for each user. The problem I have is that some users may not have any data for a particular day, so I need this to just return a 0. Here is an example of the source data and the desired outcome (notice that user02 has no data for 09/07/2016):

```
 RAW data                           Desired results

 USER    DATE        SCORE          USER    DATE        AVERAGE_SCORE
 user01  08/07/2016  0.66667        user01  08/07/2016  0.16667
 user01  08/07/2016  0.33333        user01  09/07/2016  0.66667
 user01  08/07/2016  -0.5           user01  10/07/2016  0.72222
 user01  09/07/2016  0.33333        user02  08/07/2016  0.10317
 user01  09/07/2016  0.66667        user02  09/07/2016  0.00000 <--return 0
 user01  09/07/2016  1              user02  10/07/2016  0.16270
 user01  10/07/2016  0.66667
 user01  10/07/2016  1
 user01  10/07/2016  0.5
 user02  08/07/2016  0.16667
 user02  08/07/2016  -0.14286
 user02  08/07/2016  0.28571
 user02  10/07/2016  0.66667
 user02  10/07/2016  0.57143
 user02  10/07/2016  -0.75
```

In the production database there may be dozens of users in the table, so I need to take this into account.  I am not sure the best way to approach this, I have done some simple SQL database stuff before, but this one I'm struggling with. Any help or suggestions most appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You could use a tally table and date add function to generate all the days in a given period, then left join to your query

Comment: I'd assume he's got all the data he needs, the max an min posting date gives a number of days to divide the SUM by - otherwise he could use calculation date and find days since MIN(date) - if the latest dates have no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (u NVARCHAR(50), d DATETIME, Score DECIMAL(10, 6))

INSERT INTO @TBL
SELECT 'user01' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  0.66667  SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  0.33333  SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  -0.5     SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.09' d,  0.33333  SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.09' d,  0.66667  SCORE union all       
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.09' d,  1        SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  0.66667  SCORE union all
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  1        SCORE union all
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  0.5      SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  0.16667  SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  -0.14286 SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  0.28571  SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  0.66667  SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  0.57143  SCORE 
;
with cte as 
(
   select u.[user], d.[date] 
   from       (select distinct u as [user] from @TBL) as u
   cross join (select distinct d as [date] from @TBL) as d 
)
select cte.[USER], cte.[DATE], avg(isnull(raw.SCORE,0))
from cte
left join @TBL as [raw] 
  on raw.[u] = cte.[user]
 and raw.[d] = cte.date
group by cte.[USER], cte.[DATE]
Order by cte.[USER], cte.[DATE];
```

Comment: This looks to be the sort of thing that could work - I had been looking at using a CTE to do this, but couldn't quite get the syntax right.  This one gives me a whole bunch of red in SSMS so I think the syntax is out slightly.

Comment: try a ; after the cte and the cross join was was wrong (an may still be)

Comment: Thanks @Paparazzi - this got me 95% where I needed to be, I ended up putting the results into another temporary table to process further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select 
   [USER], 
   DATE, 
   avg(SCORE) 
from tbl_name 
group by DATE,[USER] 
Order by DATE,[USER]
```

Comment: Order by should be `DATE,[USER]`

Comment: How about `user02  09/07/2016  0.00000`?

Comment: read the question.. his problem is for the users with no score for particular days

Comment: I'm assuming that each user has his own start and end date of use, therefore it is SUM(..) / No_of_days    -   including any non-participating days - if he didn't participate before or after his recorded activity - well then I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USERID, SUM(Scores) / (DATEDIFF(day,MIN(DATE),MAX(DATE))+1) 
as AVERAGE_PER_DAY  
    from table_name 
       GROUP BY USERID
```

a plausible alternative if you you want to avoid the question of non-activity at the end of the period (e.g. posted up until 2 weeks ago)

```
SELECT USERID, SUM(Scores) / (DATEDIFF(day,MIN(DATE),getdate())+1) 
as AVERAGE_PER_DAY  
    from table_name 
       GROUP BY USERID
```

Comment: my reasoning is that you need the (total of all the users scores) / (length of use)    -   I'm taking length of use in days to be based on first and last post (+1 is because we need to count FIRST AND LAST day)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME

DECLARE @TBL TABLE (u NVARCHAR(50), d DATETIME, Score DECIMAL(10, 6))

INSERT INTO @TBL
SELECT 'user01' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  0.66667  SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  0.33333  SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  -0.5     SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.09' d,  0.33333  SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.09' d,  0.66667  SCORE union all       
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.09' d,  1        SCORE union all      
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  0.66667    SCORE union all
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  1      SCORE union all
select 'user01' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  0.5        SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  0.16667    SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  -0.14286   SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.08' d,  0.28571    SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  0.66667    SCORE union all
select 'user02' u,  '2016.07.10' d,  0.57143    SCORE 


SELECT 
    @MinDate = MIN(d),
    @MaxDate = MAX(d)
FROM @TBL

;WITH Dates(dt)
AS
(
    SELECT @MinDate dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) AS dt
    FROM Dates
    WHERE 
        dt < @MaxDate
)

-- Query

SELECT 
    u,
    d,
    AVG(SCORE) SCORE        
FROM
    @TBL
GROUP BY 
    u,
    d

UNION ALL   

SELECT
    A.u,
    D.dt,
    0 Score
FROM
    Dates D CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT u FROM @TBL) A
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                u,
                d,
                MIN(d) OVER (PARTITION BY u ORDER BY (SELECT null)) MinDate,
                MAX(d) OVER (PARTITION BY u ORDER BY (SELECT null)) MaxDate
            FROM
                @TBL                
        ) T
        WHERE
            T.u = A.u AND                
            D.dt BETWEEN T.MinDate AND T.MaxDate                 
    ) AND
    D.dt NOT IN (
            SELECT T.d FROM @TBL T  
            WHERE
                T.u = A.u
    )
    ORDER BY u, d
```

Output:

```
u          d           SCORE
--------- -----------  -------------
user01    2016-07-08   0.166666
user01    2016-07-09   0.666666
user01    2016-07-10   0.722223
user02    2016-07-08   0.103173
user02    2016-07-09   0.000000
user02    2016-07-10   0.619050
```